# Simpler way to convert array into HashMap

Tags: rust

The following code would convert the max value of each color of the array into hashmap. Also in [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e876ef27407f617413198a0257e6a9af).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp;

fn main() {
    let array = [
        ("blue", 1),
        ("green", 2),
        ("red", 3),
        ("blue", 4),
        ("green", 1),
        ("red", 2),
    ];
    
    let mut scores = HashMap::new();
    
    // Convert array of key value into hashmap
    array
        .into_iter()
        .for_each(|(color, color_count)| {
            // Update the HashMap
            scores
                .entry(color)
                .and_modify(|e| { *e = cmp::max(*e, color_count) })
                .or_insert(color_count);
        });

    for (key, value) in &scores {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }
    
    println!("The product of the values: {}", scores.values().cloned().fold(1, |res, a| res * a));
}
```

It would get the following printout:

```
blue: 4
green: 2
red: 3
The product of the values: 24
```

The problem I faced is the collected `array` comes from anther `map` function. But the problem I faced is if I cast the array into `HashMap` directly the `HashMap` would store the latest entry (bottom of the array). I believe there are some neater way to chain the whole thing to make it look neater?

Comment: Use a `for` loop ([`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) itself describes a loop as more idiomatic in most cases) and the [`entry`-API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry)

Comment: Your title is *"Simpler way to convert array into HashMap"* but (according to your comments below) you actually don't care for a `HashMap` (problem X) at all, you want  the product of the per key maximum, which is a completely different problem (Y). In other words this is almost a textbook example of a XY-Problem. You might want to ask a new question with your actual problem, since this one already has answers and changing it now would invalidate those.

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for your comment. I would explain my definition of simpler properly next time.

Comment: *"The problem I faced is the collected `array` comes from another `map` function."* - Would you elaborate why this is a problem? Can't you just do the same thing anyway? Like, just remove the `.into_iter()` because it's already an iterator.

Comment: @Finomnis This is not a problem at all. My question here is not the code is not working. It is because I think the code is not neat enough. Actually the question is part of the advent of code 2023 day 2. I was just learning rust through the problems. But without a proper solution I couldn't improve my code. So I would ask in stackoverflow and see how could I improve the readability of my code. The array comes from a map is not the major problem. The problem here is I wonder if it is possible to get the desired hashmap (or end result) from the array without the for loop and chain all the way

Comment: @Winston Advent of Code has a [reddit megathread](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/188w447/2023_day_2_solutions/) for every day for this purpose. There you can find all kind of crazy solutions, including [Rust ones](https://github.com/dhruvmanila/advent-of-code/blob/master/rust/crates/year2023/src/day02.rs).

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, StackOverflow is for non-working code or code with issues. Working code should probably go into [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Finomnis I didn't know there is CodeReview. Thanks for the info. I also checked the Rust result from your sample. It seems to me that the one provided in the solution is more flexible (not fixed to only 3 colors) and neat (less line of code). So even after watching the Rust one I think I would still ask the question how to improve the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a minor change, I suggest using the [*entry* API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry), in order to avoid a first search for `.get()` and a second one for `.insert()`, but it is not very different from your own initial attempt.

```rust
    let mut scores = HashMap::<&str, usize>::new();
    for (color, color_count) in array {
        scores
            .entry(color)
            .and_modify(|c| *c = (*c).max(color_count))
            .or_insert(color_count);
    }
```

---

A totally different way of computing the product, without using a hashmap, would be to rely on the unstable [`.group_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/primitive.slice.html#method.group_by) feature (compiled with *nightly* then).

```rust
#![feature(slice_group_by)]

fn main() {
    let mut array = [
        ("blue", 1),
        ("green", 2),
        ("red", 3),
        ("blue", 4),
        ("green", 1),
        ("red", 2),
    ];

    array.sort_unstable();
    let p = array
        .group_by(|a, b| a.0 == b.0)
        .map(|g| g.last().unwrap().1)
        .product::<usize>();
    println!("product: {:?}", p);
}
/*
product: 24
*/
```

---

Without relying on unstable features, we can use [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html).

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let mut array = [
        ("blue", 1),
        ("green", 2),
        ("red", 3),
        ("blue", 4),
        ("green", 1),
        ("red", 2),
    ];

    array.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| b.cmp(a));
    let p = array
        .into_iter()
        .dedup_by(|a, b| a.0 == b.0)
        .map(|e| e.1)
        .product::<usize>();
    println!("product: {:?}", p);
}
/*
product: 24
*/
```

---

And we can come back (internally) to a hashmap...

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let array = [
        ("blue", 1),
        ("green", 2),
        ("red", 3),
        ("blue", 4),
        ("green", 1),
        ("red", 2),
    ];

    let p = array
        .into_iter()
        .into_grouping_map()
        .max()
        .into_values()
        .product::<usize>();
    println!("product: {:?}", p);
}
/*
product: 24
*/
```

Comment: Thanks I just read some document on rust and modified the question. Just wonder if it is possible to convert the hashmap in a chained manner

Comment: @Winston it's because I used `.iter()`, I just changed to `.into_iter()` as you did (actually it's implicit with a `for` loop)

Comment: I tried that on Rust Playground and it reports that and_modify got error too

Comment: @Winston It's because the closure cannot deduce the exact type of *integer* we want; just give it on the hashmap.

Comment: Thanks I learn the entry API from your example. But just wonder if it is possible to get product of the max value using from the array (may not need to use the hashmap, I use hashmap just because this is what I can think of)

Comment: @Winston to avoid such an XY-Problem you should add what you want to do into your question.

Comment: @cafce25 I would like to put everything into one chain (I request is in the question too). I am not sure how to convert the working code into a chained fashion. I tried forcing and array into hashmap but the value in the hashmap is not the max value. So I wonder if there are ways to convert the array into hashmap that stores the max value, in a chained fashion. So sorry that I confuse you guys.

Comment: Please don't post this here. Edit your question instead, and your title. Your title is definitely an XY-problem if you actually want to find the product of all max values.

Comment: Until `std` `group_by` stabilizes you could opt for [`Itertools::group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) with slightly different semantics (it's "`group_by_key`" in `std` terms)

Comment: Prefer `sort_unstable()` to `sort()` where possibe.

Comment: @Finomnis Sorry for making this XY-problem for not clarifying what I want to ask. I would also appreciate all the people spot the problem in my code and tell me there is a way to improve (e.g. EntryAPI). Although it is not part of the question but I really want to thank because if I didn't post the code snippet no one will review and help me learn not only get the solution but get the solution in a proper way. BTW this question is part of the advent of code 2023/Day 2/Part 2.

Comment: @prog-fh Thanks for making multiple edits. I learnt that there are different types of HashMap in Itertools

Answer (score 2):

When using the (pretty much standard) iterator crate [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools), this can be achieved quite easily and efficiently.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let array = [
        ("blue", 1),
        ("green", 2),
        ("red", 3),
        ("blue", 4),
        ("green", 1),
        ("red", 2),
    ];

    // Convert array of key value into hashmap
    let scores = array.into_iter().into_grouping_map().max();

    for (key, value) in &scores {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }

    println!(
        "The product of the values: {}",
        scores.into_values().fold(1, |res, a| res * a)
    );
}
```

```
blue: 4
green: 2
red: 3
The product of the values: 24
```

Also note the `into_values()` instead of `values().cloned()`.

I doubt it will be doable in a completely streamed fashion, because the first part (finding the maxima) and the second part (computing the product of the maxima) have a choke point in between. You can only start computing the product after you have looked at **all** the values, so there will be some type of data structure in between. So I think this is as good as it will get.

---

**Edit:** after looking at the source code of `into_grouping_map()`, I think that building your own `HashMap` in a `for` loop should still be more efficient. `into_grouping_map()` removes the value from the `HashMap` and re-inserts it for every item, while in your own `for` loop, you can modify the item in place.